# How to accomplish automatic update logic Xamarin forms mac OS?

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, web-applications

I have recently started to develop on macOS for Xamarin with pretty good results. Now i am touching upon the last part which is to build a system where the program is launched, the system should check if there are new updates, and if there is, update it automatically. Similir to discord and slack.

I am now drawing up how do i go about this architecturally. The initial logic is clear, during startup check for update, if there is, run update code, if there isn't launch web app.

Then the second part according to the research i've done, I see that one way to go about it is to make a rest api call to check if a new version exist by comparing existing version and then download something accordingly and handle it on the frontend.

So logic would be:

1. Launch app
2. Make rest api call to DB to compare versions
3. If new version is available download, if no new version is available do not download
4. Now to my question: What should the user download and how do i handle this in Xamarin? Downloading of files is something i've worked with prior, but I am unsure specifically on how the file / code the user will download will update the codebase.

Comment: On macOS, you would be "replacing" the entire `.app` as it is code-signed as a single entity. Now, do you publish via the App Store and let the OS handle the updates, do you prompt the user that an update is available and have them manually download the newer version, homebrew a download, replace, restart routine or use one of the many 3rd-party update frameworks (lots of open source ones) like `Squirrel.Mac`   https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Mac (not a recommendation, just a reference to want is available)

Comment: Ok i would not upload this app to app store, so would download it on a website by itself, similiar to discord.Ok i will check squirrel.Mac. Any examples of someone accomplishing this in xamarin?

Comment: I've used Sparkle and Squirrel via Xamarin.Mac, they both had upsides and downsides. Sparkle was easier to bind, but it is much much old project and has of limitations, but Squirrel (Github wrote it for their own Mac products) is so much harder to bind/interface, but so much better to use in the end... but that is strictly my experience/opinion.

Comment: Ok, is there some snippets u can show on how u accomolpished it? Would appreciate it tons

Comment: There are no code examples online from what i have seen, so it is pretty rough to find a way point to start. U know of any code snippets / documentation with this for Xamarin Mac?

Comment: I did a search on Github, several for Sparkle came up (https://github.com/toshi0607/SparkleSharpSample https://github.com/ailen0ada/SparkleSample , .... but no idea if these are complete or not, so `Caveat Emptor`), I know there were some discussion on forums.xamarin.com about Squirrel and Sparkle, so search there also.  I used the "native" examples and just converted them as I do not know if these existed at the time plus trying to get some 3rd-party projects working takes more time than doing it yourself 

Comment: for xamarin forms* sorry.

Comment: i think this will help me though, and yea ur right, maybe better to do it myself.

Comment: On your "Xamarin Forms" comment, this is a "native" platform feature set and would be implemented at the Xamarin.iOS level at least in terms of Sparkle/Squirrel.Mac in that you would not be surfacing their UI via Forms. But maybe you are using a Form's dependency service to surface a manual check/download/restart feature to link to a Forms' button command... hope that makes sense.